# How to show initial-scale 1.0 to devices below 570px width only

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website, I have a mobile version for devices below 980px, however I would like devices blow 570px only to see this and if they rotate their mobile device, for them to then be able to see the full site with their device scaling if needed.

Change my [pages](http://rafflebananza.com/admin/test.html#) width to see the mobile version. This is what I want devices to see on portrait mode but in landscape I would like them to see full version. I thought about implementing tilt detection, however nowadays you can get 27" all-in-one touch computers which can tilt!

Comment: $('meta[name="viewport"]').remove();

Comment: Please see my modified question @jme11

Comment: It's really unclear what you want to do here.  You're removing the viewport tag at 250px.  That means pretty much every device out there will have no viewport set (except maybe grandma's Motorola Razr from 2001 ;-).  Can you please explain what your intended result is?  I'm sorry if I'm thick today, but I'm not following you.

Comment: I'm wanting any device under 250px width to see my mobile version, otherwise the full version. I've just edited my question

Comment: Ok, but as I said, people using devices that have a native 250px display are highly unlikely to be surfing your site.  Also, I don't know what is meant by "my mobile version."  Does that mean you don't want the menu to collapse to the toggle?  Because that would have nothing to do with the meta-tag.

Comment: Load my site and change your screen width until you see the mobile version. My friends Blackberry z10 on portrait is 342px which I want him to see the mobile version but otherwise on landscape which is, my mistake, it is 570px, which I want him to see the full site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56064/discussion-between-jme11-and-tim-marshall).

Comment: Provided the answer I promised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have the viewport tag included, then the page will render using the device resolution.  That means it will likely return 980px not the css pixels you're expecting.  This is the [default value](https://www.google.com/search?q=default%20viewports&oq=default%20viewports&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=default%20viewport%20width) of most mobile browsers (on Android and iOS devices at least). So, trying to add the viewport tag by checking if the width of the window is less than 570px without already having the viewport content tag set to "width=device-width" would be fruitless.  This is why your first attempt did not work.

Also, if you try and remove the viewport tag AFTER the page is already rendered (for instance, inside a $(document).ready(function () {}); it would remove the tag, but the page would be unaffected.

However, you **can** set the viewport tag to have a different content value. So, in this case, you'd include the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` on the page, then in your document ready, use jQuery to set the content attribute to default width value of 980px instead. Because the DOM is ready when you are checking the width of the window, changing the value of the content attribute will cause devices that honor this property to render the page at the default 980px. (This is horribly small on my iPhone5 and impossible to use, but you stated that you find it acceptable.)

```
//add this to your document ready function and make sure 
//that the viewport is initially set to content="width=device-width"
var pageWidth = $(window).width();
if (pageWidth < 570) {
  $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=980px');   
}
```

**Why you don't have to worry about resize events:**

For most current devices that you are targeting, the window width is not resizable and the resize event will not be triggered on orientation change because it's not a change in the width of the browser, rather it's a change in zoom level.  On your desktop, however, the browser won't even care about the viewport meta tag at all, so, no matter what value you have there, it doesn't affect the behavior.